# How to get pixelcolor for given frame from mp4 files? - Without libs

Tags: video, mp4, video-processing

I want to get the pixel color for a frame from a mp4-file.

My code structure:

1. I load the file in bytes
2. I read the header file to get important information
3. I make a data struct for the mdat container

My question is now: How is the data about the shown image stored in a mp4-file?
I found this [spec-information](http://xhelmboyx.tripod.com/formats/mp4-layout.txt), but I can't figure out, how to read the needed data.

I don't want to use any libaries or packages.

I hope you can help me.
(Every hint can help)

Comment: That spec is pretty dense, but that's what you'll need to understand to *really* tackle this problem effectively -- especially if you're not using an external library. Is there something confusing about the spec you need help clarifying?

Comment: Ok I guess I didn't get the point of making mdat containers at general. 

I was analyzing one file the get the point of it: there was only one mdat container.

i previous guessed, that there were multiple parts (for audio, video etc.) 
That is not the case.

But my problem is: how is the (video-) data arranging in the file?

Comment: The video frames (also called samples) are in 'chunks' look in the spec for the sample to chunk, sample size and chunk offset boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. mp4 is just a container format. The video is compressed using a codec. The spec you pointed to will tell you how to locate a coded frame, Once you parse the mp4 file, you will need to decode the frame to read the pixel values. While it is of course 'possible' to write all this yourself, It would require tens or hundreds, of thousands of lines of code. And that is after you have studied and understood the full specification. If the video is h.264 for example, the specification is over 750 pages. And that is assume you already understand  concepts around integer inverse discreet cosine transformation, subpixel motion estimation/vectors, deblocking, content adaptive binary arithmetic coding, just to name a few things.

TLDR use a library

Comment: okay well i guess i have to use a lib... can you recomment something?

Comment: @3DExtended, why don't you google an H.264 decoder for your programming language? Once you are playing the video (decoding frames) you can "snapshot" a bitmap and extract the pixel like from any picture

Comment: So, What lib did you Use?